# Pattern matching issue with backslash

Tags: tcl

I found below description on TCL tutorial page:

> **\X**
>
> The backslash escapes a special character in globbing just the way it does in Tcl substitutions. Using the backslash lets you use glob to match a * or ?.

[Simple pattern matching - "globbing"](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl16a.html)

Then I have the following code for testing:

```
set list1 "1 2 3 *"
puts [lsearch $list1 *]
puts [lsearch $list1 \*]

set list2 "a b ? c"
puts [lsearch $list2 ?]
puts [lsearch $list2 \?]
```

However, the result is a little bit different than I expected.
All those 4 puts commands return index 0, as refer to the first element in the list.

Why doesn't `puts [lsearch $list1 \*]` and `puts [lsearch $list2 \?]` return `3` and `2`. I thought with the backslash put in front of `*` and `?`, those characters don't have any special meaning anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backslashes are also used in standard Tcl syntax to escape various characters.
You need to escape the backslash so that it is passed to the `lsearch` command.

So you need:

```
set list1 "1 2 3 *"
puts [lsearch $list1 *]
puts [lsearch $list1 \\*]
puts [lsearch $list1 {\*}] ; # or this

set list2 "a b ? c"
puts [lsearch $list2 ?]
puts [lsearch $list2 \\?]
puts [lsearch $list2 {\?}]
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help! I only tried double quotes before.

Comment: I'd prefer the `-exact` flag to `[lsearch]`: `lsearch -exact $list1 *` and `lsearch -exact $list2 ?`.